# (Multiple Questions) Python script compared to MsSQL workbench Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query ; and unique index

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

A little background, I am building up a database of stock prices for analysis (if this is not the best method, let me know). I am using MySql and running python scripts though `mysql.connector` I have a table `prices` that looks a bit like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `Prices` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_id` int,
  `ticker_id` int,
  `Open` decimal(6,2),
  `Close` decimal(6,2),
  `High` decimal(6,2),
  `Low` decimal(6,2),
  `Volume` int,
  `Adj_Open` decimal(6,2),
  `Adj_Close` decimal(6,2),
  `Adj_High` decimal(6,2),
  `Adj_Low` decimal(6,2),
  `Adj_Volume` decimal(6,2)
);
```

So far I have only stored the prices for Apple in it and it has a little over 10000 entries. I tried to select/show the table from Mysql Workbench but kept getting `Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query`. The same thing happens when I tried to truncate the table. I even increased the timeout from the 30s to 600 as suggested in one StackOverflow post, but I still get the same error.

When I run the following in python

```
def print_table(name):
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    text ="SELECT * FROM " + name
    mycursor.execute(text)
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for i in myresult:
        print(i)
    mycursor.close()

#print table prices
print_table("prices")
```

It doesn't take 2 seconds and I have a printout out of the entire table content. Is there other settings that I have to change to allow me to run these queries in workbench without getting errors.

Second question:
I would like to have a unique key based on 2 columns in the table `date_id` and `ticker_id` how can I go about setting this up. So that the following code works without entering the same date and price twice when I update the table in the future.

```
sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO prices (date_id,ticker_id,open,close,high,low,volume) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
mycursor.execute(sql,(date_id,ticker_id,p_open, p_close,p_high,p_low,p_volume))
```